# How to use variable arguments with ruby's OptionParser

Tags: ruby, optionparser

I don't know ruby very well, but I'm trying to add some functionality to this script a co-worker wrote.

Basically right now it takes a few flags and standard in as input, and it uses OptionParser to parse the flags.

I want to use OptionParser to parse a selection of command line arguments similar to those of cat. So I guess my question is how would I write the command line options parsing part of cat in ruby using OptionParser

```
cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

Hope that makes sense, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to deal with the non-switch ([FILE]) arguments?

Comment: Yes, I was able to write code for all of the switch options, but I don't know how to deal with the infinite number of files listed after that. Sorry I was unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer.  After parsing all the options, you should be left with ARGV as an array of filenames.  Assuming that the user has entered a valid commandline, that is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
OPTS = {}

op = OptionParser.new do |x|
    x.banner = 'cat <options> <file>'      
    x.separator ''

    x.on("-A", "--show-all", "Equivalent to -vET")               
        { OPTS[:showall] = true }      

    x.on("-b", "--number-nonblank", "number nonempty output lines") 
        { OPTS[:number_nonblank] = true }      

    x.on("-x", "--start-from NUM", Integer, "Start numbering from NUM")        
        { |n| OPTS[:start_num] = n }

    x.on("-h", "--help", "Show this message") 
        { puts op;  exit }

end

op.parse!(ARGV)

# Example code for dealing with filenames
ARGV.each{ |fn| output_file(OPTS, fn) }
```

I shall leave other command line operations, as they say, as an exercise for the reader!  You get the idea.

(NB: I had to invent a fictional -x parameter to demo passing a value after a flag.)

Update: I should have explained that this will leave ARGV as an array of filenames, assuming that the user has entered any.

Comment: So the issue with this is it supports only one file. What I'm really trying to figure out is how to deal with the fact that there is 4 files on command line. Lets say a call like "cat a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt".

Comment: Nope, ARGV should be an array with one element for each word left on the command line after the options are processed.  In your example it would have four elements.

Comment: @icco `puts ARGV.inspect # => ["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt", "d.txt"]`